# How to find a replacement motherboard fan?

Tags: motherboard, fan

My old motherboard (Gigabyte GA-2CEWH) has two such fans. As you can see on the picture, one of them is no longer spinning.

The machine “mostly” works, but needs a few hours between shutting down and starting again to cool...

Motherboard manual identifies the location of the fan as “CK804”. How do I search for a suitable replacement?
[image: fan pulled out][image: fans in a working system]

Comment: Any 3-pin 1.5 inch low profile fan should work.  [You can find those exact fans on Ebay and Amazon though](https://www.bing.com/search?q=S124010DM&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=undefined&sc=0-9&sk=&cvid=F70A2F52730247D68B6AE7F7CF7DFC18)

Comment: Any 40 mm x 40 mm x 10 mm fan will work.

Comment: Thank you. But, aren't there _improved_ models since the machine was made 20 years ago?

Comment: The motherboard in question isn't 20 years old.  A 40 mm fan is a 40 mm fan.

Comment: While a fan that recesses into heat sink will provide a little more air flow through the fins themselves  CFM for CFM, I would personally install a higher CFM 20mm tall fan without giving it a second thought.  The trick would be getting the proper screws but heat and airflow would not be a problem and then I would have a more standard fan for future repairs/replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label CK804 is the chipset, does not necessarily help to determine the required fan.
The broken fan 40mm, search for the model number "S124010DM". Due to its mounting it will not consume any (or much) extra height.

**Beware of other 40mm fans, as they will not recess into the heatsink!**

To explain my concerns further, a regular fan will stick out by its height, which might be 10mm or more depending on the model. The original fan was mounted below its screw holes, so it will not add any significant height. This can be seen in the first image.

This may or may not be problematic, but has to be considered, as it will change the effective height of the cooler. This might cause issues for some other parts occupying the space in the server case. At least the airflow is changed to a certain extent.

Comment: Pictures of the motherboard at a different angle, indicate the 40 mm fans on the motherboard, are just standard 40 mm fans.

Comment: I disagree. The first image in the question clearly shows the fan to be "below" the screw holes, it is placed upside down on the table. If you were to mount a "regular" fan with a box, the fan will "end" at the height of the heatsink and protrude by at least 1cm or how thick the chosen fan is. This might cause issues for some other parts occupying the space in the server case.

Comment: The two fans in question are for the `nForce Professional 2200` and `nForce Professional 2250`.Northbridge.  They are standard 10 mm tall fans based on a screenshot provided by Gigabyte.

Comment: @c11o is right, the currently-mounted fans both descend into the circular recesses in the heatsinks. Although there is plenty of room for a taller fan, I'm worried about a replacement being "too far" from the heatsink, unless it fits into the same recess. But now I know, what to search for. Thanks, everybody.

Comment: Any fan will work, the chips you will be cooling, are not going to get that hot.

Answer (score 2):

Fans are sold in standardized sizes, typically measured in millimeters. Rough conversion from your measurement in the picture gets us about 40 mm (1.5 inches = ~38.1 mm), so in lieu of more precise measurement we will assume that your fans are 40 mm standard. You can use a metric ruler / measuring tape to confirm.

You will want to confirm that the fans use a 3-pin header / connector, as that's what your current fans have. This shouldn't be hard as the 3-pin is a long lived standard at this point and most (if not all) interior case fans will use it.

---

Example link:

https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Description=40mm%20fan&Submit=ENE

A simple internet search should find you a few retailers from whom you can order a suitable replacement. Amazon, Newegg, or any number of other retailers should have these available.

---

Since these are quite cheap I'd recommend replacing both of those fans pictured, since that dust layer can make them less effective.

You may also want to look into improving case airflow and potentially replacing your CPU thermal paste. Having your computer shut down from overheating is not great, but having to let it cool for that long before it is operable is unusual to say the least. There's definitely potential for a bigger / more complex problem than a single broken fan, but any more information or opinions on that are outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @Ramhound Apparently my brain doesn't work this morning, appreciate the correction. I've edited my answer to reflect your superior ruler observation skills.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very popular size and connection type. So you can find it for example on eBay or Aliexpress (40mm, 3 pin).
Until then, temporary, you can try to add 1 small drop oil or WD40 into the middle of the fan on both sides into the bearing.

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/1-PC-EVERFLOW-S124010DM-Fan-12V-0-08A-2-Pin-40-40mm-K1622-LL-/171887890696

Comment: Will any such replacement fit into the depression made for it in the little heatsink underneath?

Comment: There is nothing special about the 40 mm fan you have currently

Comment: Some of the 40x40x10 fans available seem [too thick](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B071H815X2/), which would prevent them from going into the heatsink...

Comment: Honestly based on the screenshots I have found of the motherboard provided by Gigabyte, those don't even appear to be the original fans, that came with the board anyways.  *In any event if you are worried the same fan can be purchased.*

Comment: I do not understand your concern about the thickness unless you don't have enough space over it, which is also bad for the proper cooling. The size 40mmx40mm. Any fan will fit in If the fan has a frame on the top and bottom side, you will need longer screws (+10mm or...). 
But if you want exactly the same in non-transparent version:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/1-PCS-EVERFLOW-Fan-S124010DM-DC-12V-0-08A-3-Pin-40-40mm/252394615714?hash=item3ac3e433a2:g:WHoAAOSwADNXPLz2

Comment: The current fans fit into the round depression in the heat-sink, @Leslie, because the "lower" side of each has no frame, only the "upper" side has "ears" for the screws. Some of what's for sale has ears on both sides, or even a solid-plastic frame -- and will not fit. But, yeah, I think, I know, how to find it now. Thank you!

Comment: I see.
You have 2 option. 
Replace the fan with the exact same, I linked it. 
The second option you put on a regular one. It will be fine.
More consideration can be the noise and the lifetime. (quality, price)

Comment: Khm, everything coming up in the search is similarly "two-sided" -- and [the one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/EVERFLOW-S124010DM-Fan-DC-12V-0-08A-40-40mm-2-Pin-/252394619852) linked-to by @Ramhound is a 2-pin variant, not 3-pin. Is there a name for the "one-sided" form-factor, or do I just have to examine them all to find it?

Comment: Here is the 3 pin variant:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/1-PCS-EVERFLOW-Fan-S124010DM-DC-12V-0-08A-3-Pin-40-40mm/252394615714?hash=item3ac3e433a2:g:WHoAAOSwADNXPLz2

Comment: Thanks, @Leslie, but that's a slightly different 3pin connector from what I've got. Yeah, I can probably slice it myself...

Answer (score -2):

open cmd, run cmd, type the command `wmic bios get serialnumber`

This will return the serial number that you can use on the manufacturers site to look up exactly what parts etc your system takes.

Comment: The command you suggested only works on OEM devices.  The author has a server motherboard, which means the information that normally would be printed with the command you suggested, will not be filled out.

Comment: Lesson learned! Interesting and i'm glad to know that now!

Although given that it wasn't mentioned that it was a server motherboard in the question and my answer would work for a PC, I feel the loss of 2 of the 3 rep points I had on this account was unjust. Oh well.

Comment: It actually was mentioned it was a [server motherboard](http://b2b.gigabyte.com/Server-Motherboard/GA-2CEWH-rev-10), the author indicated they had a `Gygabyte GA-2CEWH`, which of course is a server motherboard. **You lost no reputation, you had 1 reputation when you submitted this answer, and you still have 1 reputation.**  The downvotes to an answer, that was submitted in haste, is completely justified.  Perhaps spending more time on the quality of your answer, verifying your solution actually is applicable to the author's situation, before submitting your answers in the future is warranted.

Comment: I see you had earned 2 reputation from accepting an answer to a question you submitted.  The downvotes you this answer has received is more then justified.

Comment: I wasn't really having a go over the two points, was trying to make light of my mistake, i'm not bothered by that at all, I'll just sit back down, cheers for the education!

Comment: Could have fooled me.  When somebody claims something is not justified.  I take that statement seriously.

Comment: I don't think anyone in their right mind would have any particularly strong feelings about any fluctuation in score on an A/C this low.. 

I'm sorry that I offended you so much my friend, I genuinely do appreciate the lesson on wmic usage and reading questions.

Comment: Well, @Ramhound, if you do listen to concerns over unjust reputation-decreases, maybe, you can explain, why _I_ have lost 4 points over this question? It is neither off-topic nor frivolous, yet two people downgraded it...

Comment: The voters didn't "downgrade" it, they downvoted it, because they found it unhelpful.  I already addressed the fact I didn't notice you earned 2 reputation for accepting an answer to your question.  You didn't offend me in the slightest, takes more to offend me, then a user who submits an answer they didn't validate before submitting.  *I actually don't care the answer isn't applicable to the author*